# sql - return max value for a time period in two tables

Tags: sql, join, max

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

I have two tables:

**Students**:

```
ST_STUDENT_ID  NAME   ST_DATE_TAKEN
-------------  -----  -------------
1              Jim    2011-01-01
2              Fred   2011-01-02
3              Sarah  2011-01-03
4              Nancy  2001-02-04
```

**SCORES**:

```
SC_STUDENT_ID  SC_SCORE
-------------  --------
1              97
2              97
3              95
4              97
```

I need to pull the student with the highest score for a month (say January). However, I only want one student even if multiple students received that score and that score could also exist outside my focus month, so this is complicating my query. The only way I could figure to do it was to redo all my criteria at each nested sub-query. Is there a better way. It wasn't too terrible here, but in my actual problem the where criteria is much more complicated and joined across many tables, duplicating it is a pain, plus the cost gets quite large.

```
SELECT ST_STUDENT_ID, ST_TIMESTAMP, SC_SCORE
FROM STUDENTS 
JOIN SCORES
  ON ST_STUDENT_ID = SC_STUDENT_ID
WHERE ST_STUDENT_ID = (
  SELECT MAX(ST_STUDENT_ID)
  FROM STUDENTS
  JOIN SCORES
    ON ST_STUDENT_ID = SC_STUDENT_ID
  WHERE ST_TIMESTAMP > '2011-01-01'
    AND ST_TIMESTAMP < '2011-02-01'
    AND SC_SCORE IS NOT NULL
    AND SC_SCORE = (
      SELECT MAX(SC_SCORE)
        FROM STUDENTS
      JOIN SCORES
        ON ST_STUDENT_ID = SC_STUDENT_ID
      WHERE ST_TIMESTAMP > '2011-01-01'
        AND ST_TIMESTAMP < '2011-02-01'))
```

Comment: With what criteria are you selecting one student from the multiple students with same score in that particular month?

Comment: What's the point of finding a top student for a past month if the Scores table hasn't got any timestamp showing *when* that score was achieved? Or what am I missing?

Comment: @Andriy M - one guess might be is that this is a schema designed to avoid NULLs - the row in the STUDENTS table is added when they enrol for an exam. Once they've taken the exam, and a result is available, this is stored as a row in SCORES. Other than that, yes, it does seem a little funny.

Comment: @Damien: Given the table names (the `Student` name, at least), yes, there does seem to be some sense in that this pair of tables is essentially a normalised single `Students` table. But then why would `ST_DATE_TAKEN` be stored separately from `SC_SCORE`? They seem to belong together. But I'm getting overly critical, and I'm possibly still missing some crucial details to judge correctly.

Comment: This was just part of a larger query on several other joined tables (I thought that would be too much information to put all on here). Since this was the part with which I was having trouble, I posted that here and figured I could use the answer in my larger query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one score, and your time period will be passed explicitly into the query, what about something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 ST_STUDENT_ID, ST_TIMESTAMP, SC_SCORE
FROM STUDENTS 
JOIN SCORES ON ST_STUDENT_ID = SC_STUDENT_ID
WHERE ST_TIMESTAMP >= '2011-01-01'
AND ST_TIMESTAMP <= '2011-02-01'
ORDER BY SC_SCORE DESC, ST_STUDENT_ID DESC
```

That syntax should work for MS SQL Server - different RDBMSs have slightly different syntaxes for the "TOP 1" concept.

[I see from your later comment that you're using DB2 - in which case the syntax apparently is `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.]

Note that I'm following the logic in your example, which implies the student with the highest ID takes precedence.  Good incentive to register late for class ;-)

Comment: I had looked at doing something along these lines, but I heard that max was better to use than ordered by, so that was why I was trying to use it...but it led to all the sub-queries. Is there any rule about when to use one vs. the other?

Comment: I guess MAX is "purer" and more standard SQL - so your original query tells the RDBMS very explicitly and declaratively what it logically needs to return.  Nothing wrong with that (though check the nuances of < and > vs <= and >=).  It can get problematic in practice because - as you alluded - the query becomes complex to write and the cost is high because it's more difficult for the RDBMS to optimise smartly.  If you know you want 'n' records - including the case where 'n' = 1, then TOP (or LIMIT or whatever your RDBMS calls it) is a good and cheaper shortcut - here you have a single join...

Comment: ...and a single ORDER BY (and it doesn't matter too much for cost how many columns you include in your ordering).

Comment: Yeah, I just tried your "order by" solution (which I had been trying to avoid and it came back almost half the cost as my max solution...so it seems much better all around.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming SQL Server 2005 or later, or another RDMBS that supports CTEs and window functions)

Something like:

```
;With OrderedScores as (
SELECT
    ST_STUDENT_ID,
    ST_TIMESTAMP,
    SC_SCORE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SC_SCORE desc,newid()) as rn /* Ordered randomly within same score */
FROM
    STUDENTS
        join
    SCORES
        on ST_STUDENT_ID = SC_STUDENT_ID
WHERE
    ST_TIMESTAMP >= '20110101' and
    ST_TIMESTAMP < '20110201'
)
select * from OrderedScores where rn = 1
```

Obviously, you can play with the criteria within the `ORDER BY` of the window function, to determine which student you pick when ties exist (in the above it's random; again assuming SQL Server - if another RDBMS, `newid()` should be replaced with something else)

In addition, I think I've got your date criteria correct here - in your original query, you have one set of criteria that use `>` and `<` (so excluding Jim), and in the other, you use `<=` and `>=`, which could include a student who tested on 1st Feb.

Comment: You are correct with my criteria (sorry, error in simplifying it from my bigger query).
Unfortunately, we are running IBM DB2 (v9) on a mainframe, which does not support the windows functions, sorry should have included that in the original post.